# maketrans alternative for list - python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, translate

```
INPUT = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k"]
OUTPUT = ["20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"]
TABLE = maketrans(INPUT, OUTPUT)
content = content.translate(TABLE)
```

> TypeError: maketrans() argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not list

What I want is, for example, if string = "a", the return to be "20".

I cannot turn INPUT and OUTPUT into strings because they would have different size.

What is the most efficient alternative or tweak?

Comment: Use a dict like `TABLE = str.maketrans(dict(zip(INPUT,OUTPUT))) `

Comment: different version @Dark

Comment: Then you should use a different tool other than translate. You *could* make a dict, and use `''.join([d[c] for c in content])`

Comment: example, "a" to "20"     example,"b" to "21"      example,"c" to "22". There is a clear pattern. I have read the documentation.

Comment: So using a dict din't help you get the results??

Comment: You know you can use the builtin `ord()`: `def letter_to_number(c): return str(ord(c) - ord('a') +20)` , and you can gate that to return the character otherwise `def f(c): return str(ord(c) - 77) if 'a' <= c <= 'k' else c`

Comment: ...but ultimately why are you trying to do this, it feels like an XY problem? Are you trying to parse into tokens? or modify encodings/decodings? or what?

Comment: @smci encodings/decodings. solved now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `izip_longest` (Python 2.x) or `zip_longest` (Python 3.x):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

INPUT = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k"]
OUTPUT = ["20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"]

string = 'a'   # string here

for i, o in izip_longest(INPUT, OUTPUT):
    if i == string:
        print(o)
# 20
```